# Retrieve Arabic Data From Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple search using PHP and MySQL

it works perfectly for English text, but for Arabic text it will not retrieve any data without any Error

while executing the same MySQL query on Database "PhpMyAdmin" works perfectly

Result.PHP

---

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["search"])){$_POST["search"]="";}
echo $search=$_POST["search"];  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "aramtryf_laravel";
$password = "Reha@2015";
$dbname = "aramtryf_laravel";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($conn,$sSQL); 

$sql = "  SELECT * FROM oldorgs WHERE org_name like '%$search%'  ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {



echo    "<tr>
      <th scope='row'>".$row["org_name"]."</th>
      <td>".$row["gov"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["sector"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["email"]."</td>

    </tr>";


    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: have you tried, mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
instead of that query.

Comment: Hi @yasoh it Worked perfectly Thanks How Can I make ur answer as as correct answer

Comment: i've added my comment as answer now if you want to vote for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($conn,$sSQL);
```

try

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely works :  Your html page set to meta data UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

OR 
In Mysql try this

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("arabicd", $connect);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: @Rebaz:  If you happy with my answer can you please up vote then. please

Comment: Hi   , Thanks for support, I tried @yasoh s answer ,it worked perfectly

Comment: Ok as you wish. (y) Keep programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

after the you connect to mysql.

or you can use this one.

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a partial implementation of UTF-8. So I'd suggest you stick to the HTML UTF-8 for example:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Or you can use **utf8mb4** to fully support UTF-8 in mysql.

Comment: Hi @Mawia I also added ur suggestion but with same issue