# Need help to filter arabic database records using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]

```
Verse::where('text','Like','ٱللَّهِ')->get()
```

i tried a package but its not useful for me

```
 $mode="1";
    $Arabic = new Arabic();
    $Arabic->setQueryStrFields('text');
    $Arabic->setQueryMode($mode);
    $keyword = str_replace('\"', '"', $string);
    $strCondition = $Arabic->arQueryWhereCondition($keyword);
    $strOrderBy   = $Arabic->arQueryOrderBy($keyword);
    $result=DB::table('verses')->select(DB::raw('text',$strCondition,$strOrderBy))->limit(10)->get();
```

i have databse like this and i want to search a specific string using laravel but getting empty result , please give me a suggestion to handle this
i am using laravel 8

Comment: `where('text', 'like', '%ٱللَّهِ%')`

Comment: no its not working i did this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL diacritic insensitive search (Arabic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863402/mysql-diacritic-insensitive-search-arabic)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616682/searching-arabic-words-that-have-diacritics-in-mysql/18625906, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851281/searching-arabic-with-diacritics-in-mysql,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443740/searching-arabic-names-discard-the-differences-between-%D8%A3-%D8%A7-in-mysql, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275374/retrieve-arabic-data-from-database/53275499, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073163/mysql-full-text-search-with-utf8-persian-arabic, ...

Comment: hey man this issue is resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443740/searching-arabic-names-discard-the-differences-between-%D8%A3-%D8%A7-in-mysql I already tested the first solution hope you find it helpful